# Angularjs: change input type Dynamically

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a list which sometimes has `true` or `false` value. When I'm using `ng-repeat` to show the list with the value inside an `<input type="text">` , I'd like to have `<input type="checkbox">` if the value matches a boolean.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="parameter in parameter_list">
            <th class="text-left">
                {{parameter.title | uppercase}}
            </th>
            <td class="text-left">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" ng-model="parameter_list[$index].value" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas, how can I achieve this ?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp5rcm8j/)

**Edit :** It's not a duplicate since I don't have the `input` `type` in a `$scope` variable.

Comment: You may need to convey this "The problem with this is that I don't have the input type in a $scope variable." some where in your post which saves from Duplicates issue for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend more generic approach. First of all if you want to differentiate your inputs by type you need to declare some type checking function in your controller:

```
$scope.getType = function(x){
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x);
}
```

You need to do this because it's impossible to do this in the expression - see: [How to get a type of scope variable in Angular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862731/how-to-get-a-type-of-scope-variable-in-angular-expression)

Then in your view you can use ng-if directive to show different controls depending on the type of the field. This is example expression for booleans:

```
ng-if="getType(parameter_list[$index].value) == '[object Boolean]'"
```

You should also define your booleans correctly, not "true"/"false" but true/false:

```
{
        "title": "differed",
        "value": true
}
```

Finally the code of your example would look as follows.

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
        <div>
          <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="parameter in parameter_list">
                    <th class="text-left">
                        {{parameter.title | uppercase}}
                    </th>
                    <td class="text-left">
                      <div class="form-group" ng-if="getType(parameter_list[$index].value) != '[object Boolean]'">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="parameter_list[$index].value" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group checkbox" ng-if="getType(parameter_list[$index].value) == '[object Boolean]'">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="parameter_list[$index].value">{{ parameter_list[$index].title }} </label>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.getType = function(x){
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x);
  }

    $scope.parameter_list = [
    {
        "title": "name",
        "value": "Product3"
    },
    {
        "title": "version",
        "value": "01.00.00"
    },
    {
        "title": "inventory_name",
        "value": "Product3"
    },
    {
        "title": "inventory_version",
        "value": "01.00.00"
    },
    {
        "title": "differed",
        "value": true
    },
    {
        "title": "differed_name",
        "value": "whatever"
    },
    {
        "title": "accept_error_while_reboot",
        "value": false
    },
    {
        "title": "setup",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "ggg",
        "value": "setup.exe"
    },
    {
        "title": "fx",
        "value": "test"
    },
    {
        "title": "gx",
        "value": "setup.exe"
    },
    {
        "title": "tx",
        "value": "setup.exe"
    }
]
  });
```

Here you can find JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57qhsqwf/2/

Answer (score 16):

Just keep it simple:

```
<input type="{{typeInput}}" />
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.typeInput = 'number';
```

Works like a charm, without all that extra code

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't have the input type in a $scope variable.

Comment: this wont work with ng-model i guess, after type and input data change the model will get undefined

Comment: Works superbly -
`<input class="form-row-input" ng-model="vm.user.password" type="{{vm.typeInput}}" name="pass"/>

CHECK BOX to enable / disable -
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.showPassword"/>

In Controller -
$scope.$watch('vm.showPassword',function(newVal){
                if(newVal) {
                    vm.typeInput = 'text';
                }
                else {
                    vm.typeInput = 'password';
                }
            }); `

Comment: I did the same method, in chrome inspector I am not seeing the input `type` change from `text` to `tel`.  The controller console.log shows the type output changing from text to tel, but its not reflecting so in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can define **ngShow** and **ngHide**.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/om8xaps2/1/)

[EDIT FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/om8xaps2/2/)

If you want to use show;

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-show="parameter_list[$index].value==false || parameter_list[$index].value==true " ng-model="parameter_list[$index].value" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" ng-show="parameter_list[$index].value!=false && parameter_list[$index].value!=true " ng-model="parameter_list[$index].value" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Or you can send object with `isChecked` value.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-show="parameter_list[$index].isChecked" ng-model="parameter_list[$index].value" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" ng-show="!parameter_list[$index].isChecked" ng-model="parameter_list[$index].value" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: @BipBip if you don't want to set other input you can use ngInıt to.

Comment: @BipBip "value": "true" is a string :)

Comment: I just noticed actually when I click the checkbox, it's getting back to `text`, which is normal http://jsfiddle.net/eynvqnL6/. How can we solve it ?

Comment: @BipBip You have two option. 1. Send data with boolean not string. Or 2. filter data with string or boolean like value=='false' OR value=='false' OR value=='true' OR value==false OR value==true

Comment: Can you make a fiddle please ?

Comment: As far as I remember `ng-show`/`ng-hide` could be trouble maker because angular will only hide those fields so there will be two inputs with the same name if you'd set name property, and bound to the same scope variable. I'd recommend using `ng-if` instead.

Comment: @Landeeyo You are right. NgInıt or NgIf very usefull. It is a simple example for 'BipBip' . Now he/she can use any directive.

Answer (score 2):

I updated your jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/jp5rcm8j/2/

I use `ng-show` directive to check when the value is tru or false and create dynamically checkbox that could be checked or not.

```
<input ng-show="parameter_list[$index].value !=true && parameter_list[$index].value !=false" type="text" ng-model="parameter_list[$index].value" class="form-control">

<input ng-show="parameter_list[$index].value==true || parameter_list[$index].value==false" type="checkbox" ng-model="parameter_list[$index].value" class="form-control">
```

**1.** There is a problem though with the '`setup`' property, **you left it empty** so the angular reads it as `false` and creates a checkbox. Could you just add a value different than null? That would solve the problem completely.

**2.** i changed your **'true'** and **'false'** values to **true** and **false** without the **'** symbol , for the angular to understand that is boolean and not string value.

Hope helps ,good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-switch to achieve your goal according to the value of the property that is either true or false!

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="parameter in parameter_list">
        <th class="text-left">
            {{parameter.title | uppercase}}
        </th>
        <td class="text-left">
          <div class="form-group" ng-switch="parameter_list[$index].value">
            <input type="text" ng-model="parameter_list[$index].value" class="form-control" ng-switch-when="true">
```

Cheers! :)