# HTML Input Filter File Types

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to do something quite simple but it's not filtering anything and it shows "All Files".
This must be dynamic code.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" accept="{{fileType}}" />
```

JS (removed the if clause):

```
  if(false) {
            $scope.fileType = "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text";
        }
        else {
            $scope.fileType = "application/pdf"; // Only PDF files should be shown
        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: When you examine the DOM, does it look correct? What part is failing? Need to see more of your code because it looks like it should work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862140/angularjs-change-input-type-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can use this JavaScript for checking the file type and allowing only certain file types:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var validFilesTypes = ["bmp", "gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "rar", "zip", "txt", "pdf"]; 
/* you can enter all your required file types in the above line */

    function CheckExtension(file) {
        /*global document: false */
        var filePath = file.value;
        var ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        var isValidFile = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < validFilesTypes.length; i++) {
            if (ext == validFilesTypes[i]) {
                isValidFile = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isValidFile) {
            file.value = null;
            alert("Invalid File. Valid extensions are:\n\n" + validFilesTypes.join(", "));
        }

        return isValidFile;
    }
</script>
```

This code stores all the required file types in the `validFilesTypes` variable.
You can change the values stored in it to your required file types.